# Stacky points detect nilpotent cohomology

Tags: cohomology, algebraic-stacks

Take a finite type scheme $X/\mathbf{C}$ acted on by a reductive group $G$. Then $X/G$ is an Artin stack. Let $\alpha\in H^*(X/G)$ be a rational cohomology class on it.

**Question:** Is it true that $\alpha$ is nilpotent if and only if its pullback to any stacky point $BH\to X/G$ is torsion?

For instance, if the action is trivial, $X/G=X\times BG$, and $\alpha=(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$ is not nilpotent iff $\alpha_0=1$ and $\alpha_1$ is not nilpotent. This is precisely the condition that its pullback by a stacky point $BG\to X/G$ is not torsion. The idea is that the infinite cohomology is "captured" by the stabiliser groups.

*Following question:* is this result true for general Artin stacks (perhaps with conditions)?

Comment: Finite type scheme over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: What does it mean for a rational cohomology class to be torsion?

Comment: @DanPetersen Apologies, that was a typo, I meant _nilpotent_ (so that $H^*(X/G)$ is a torsion $k[\alpha]$ module).